# JQuery - Swapping two elements does not work after first move

Tags: javascript, jquery, bubble-sort

I have a function to do a bubble sort among content of various `div`s. for each swap operation, it swaps the divs too, using `JQuery Swapsies plugin`. The problem is tht it does the swap once, and after that for other swap operations:

```
function swap(id1, id2){

$('#' +id1).swap({
  target: id2,
  opacity: "0.5",
  speed: 1000,
  callback: function() {


  }
});

}

function bubbleSort() {

var ret=[];
$(".num-div").each(function(){ ret.push($(this));});

let swapped;
do {
  swapped = false;
  for (let i = 1; i < ret.length; ++i) {

    if (ret[i - 1].html() > ret[i].html()) {
      swap(ret[i-1].attr('id'), ret[i].attr('id'));
      [ret[i], ret[i - 1]] = [ret[i - 1], ret[i]];

      swapped = true;

    }
  }
} while (swapped);
return ret;
```

}

In the first step where `i=1` it works and swaps `ret[i-1]` with `ret[i]`, but after that it does not work.

Comment: What is the result output of ret? Seems to be an async problem. And maybe, `ret[i - 1].html()` should be `parseInt(ret[i - 1].text())`?

Comment: Also, for bubble sort, you have to go back one iteration if you do a swap.

Comment: It is the sorted array. it is supposed to sort the array and displace divs using swap() function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `swap` plug-in will not process calls when it is busy with an animation. You can see that in the [source code](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/joehanna/swapsies/master/js/jquery-swapsies.js) of the plug-in:

```
if (options.target!="" && !swapping) {
```

The `swapping` variable will be `true` during an ongoing animation, and that `if` will just skip any new animation without notice.

Anyway, you probably want the animations to happen in sequence, not all at the same time. For that purpose I would suggest using promises and the rather new `async/await` syntax.

First you would promisify the `swap` function, so it returns a promise. Then you add the `async` and `await` keywords at the appropriate spot, and ... it will work.

One more caution: if your data is numerical, and you want to sort by numeric value, you need to convert strings to numbers before doing the comparison, for instance by applying the unary `+` like this: `+ret[i].text()`

Here is a working demo:

```js
function swap(id1, id2){
    return new Promise(resolve => 
        $('#' +id1).swap({
          target: id2,
          opacity: "0.5",
          speed: 500,
          callback: resolve
        })
    );
}

async function bubbleSort() {
    var ret=[];
    $(".num-div").each(function(){ 
        ret.push($(this));
    });

    let swapped;
    do {
        swapped = false;
        for (let i = 1; i < ret.length; ++i) {
            if (ret[i - 1].text() > ret[i].text()) {
                await swap(ret[i-1].attr('id'), ret[i].attr('id'));
                [ret[i], ret[i - 1]] = [ret[i - 1], ret[i]];
                swapped = true;
            }
        }
    } while (swapped);
    return ret;
}

bubbleSort().then( ret => {
    console.log($.map(ret, x => $(x).text()));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://biostall.com/wp-content/uploads/2010/07/jquery-swapsies.js"></script>
<div id="i1" class="num-div">sort</div>
<div id="i2" class="num-div">these</div>
<div id="i3" class="num-div">words</div>
<div id="i4" class="num-div">in</div>
<div id="i5" class="num-div">alphabetical</div>
<div id="i6" class="num-div">order</div>
```